# VBA6 -> VBA7 - Problems converting code to 64 bit - Bring window to foreground (AutoCAD 2014)

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel, autocad-plugin

I am working on converting some very old VBA code to run on AutoCAD 2014. I have so far converted everything but there is an issue with the forms (they are modeless and require an activation callback to modify the window propertis). The following is the VBA6 source code:

IN THE FORM:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
#If ACAD2000 = 0 Then
    If Not bPopup Then
        Call EnumWindows(AddressOf EnumWindowsProc, vbNull)
        Call SubClass
        bPopup = True
    End If
#End If
End Sub
```

MODULE (named modModeLessFormFocus):

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
Declare Function EnumWindows Lib "user32" (ByVal lpEnumFunc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, ByVal cch As Long) As Long

Private ThisHwnd As Long
Public Const GWL_STYLE = -16
Public Const WS_POPUP = &H80000000

Function EnumWindowsProc(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Integer

    Dim title As String * 32
    Call GetWindowText(hwnd, ByVal title, 32)
    If InStr(title, "About") Then
        ThisHwnd = hwnd
        EnumWindowsProc = False
    ElseIf InStr(title, "Preferences") Then
        ThisHwnd = hwnd
        EnumWindowsProc = False
    ElseIf InStr(title, "Display Block Attributes") Then
        ThisHwnd = hwnd
        EnumWindowsProc = False
    Else
        EnumWindowsProc = True
    End If
End Function

Public Function SubClass() As Long
    Dim Flags As Long
    Flags = GetWindowLong(ThisHwnd, GWL_STYLE)
    Flags = Flags Xor WS_POPUP
    SetWindowLong ThisHwnd, GWL_STYLE, Flags
End Function
```

The error I get when running is a "Type Mismatch" in UserForm_Activate on 'AddressOf EnumWindowsProc.' I have tried to convert it to 64bit using PtrSafe and PtrLong but inevitably it fails and the program crashes.

If anyone is smart enough to convert this or point me in the right direction I would be very appreciative.

Thanks

Comment: Not 100% it's the issue, but this looks weird `Dim title As String * 32`. Also, you've shown `EnumWindowsProc`, but not `EnumWindows`. Are you sure the issue isn't there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the API for 64-bit VBA7 in http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp

```
#If VBA7 Then
    #If Win64 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "USER32" Alias "GetWindowLongPtrA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
    #Else
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "USER32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr
    #End If
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowText Lib "USER32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
                                      (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, ByVal lpString As String, _
                                       ByVal cch As LongPtr) As Long

#Else
    Private Declare Function GetWindowLongPtr Lib "USER32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long 
    Private Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "USER32" Alias "GetWindowTextA" _
                                      (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String, _
                                       ByVal cch As Long) As Long
#End If
```

You can also look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383663(VS.85).aspx for the updated API

Comment: @ja72 Your 5th line is missing the PtrSafe attribute.

Comment: @Rory it seems so. I just copied from the linked website. Fixed!

Comment: @ja72 - I didn't realise that. I'll let JK know his page needs correcting! Thanks.